# Is there a way to duplicate views for localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

As my website has a lot of content, is there a way to duplicate views for each language ?
For example, I would have some views like About_en.cshtml, About_fr.cshtml, About_es.cshtml

Then call the right view depending on the selected language using filters. Don't really know how to achieve it but here is an idea:

```
var v = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(
filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext,
viewResult.ViewName + "_" + defaultLang, null
    );
if (v.View != null)
viewResult.ViewName += "_" + defaultLang;
```

Or maybe do you have another idea than the resource files for website having a lot of content.
Thank you.

Comment: Instead of multiple views make one view which can be automatically translated based on current user culture. In this way you are able to maintain your code in simple way without multiple adjustments to multiple views

Comment: You mean using the ressource files ? Because that’s what I want to avoid as I have huge portions of text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily make it conditional within the function. All you have to do is to simply mention the name of that view while returning from the function :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Foo(string lang)
{
    string ViewName = "";

    if (lang == "French")
    {
         ViewName = "About_fr";
    }
    else if (lang == "English")
    {
         ViewName = "About_en";
    }
    else
    {
         ViewName = "About_es";
    }

    return View(ViewName);
}
```

The above will do the trick. Furthermore, if you have a model bound to the view, you can simply pass the model as a second parameter :

```
return View(ViewName, model);
```

Comment: Thank you. But how do I retrieve the lang value ?

Comment: According to the question you've asked, you've mentioned that you will be calling the right view depending upon the **selected language**. You can simply pass that selected language as a parameter to your function. I've updated my answer!

Comment: Yes got it. But maybe retrieve it from the url directly would be better ? Any way to do it within the function itself ? Sorry this is my first project on Asp...

Comment: No problem. Well this is another topic. As far as your question is concerned, I believe, I've already answered it. You can ask another question for that. The simplest way I can tell you within the thread is that you can make this function as `[HttpGet]` and pass the `lang` value through the query string. Look [here](https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/asp-net-mvc5/asp-net-mvc-5-httpget-and-httppost-method-with-example.php)